# Facebook Graph API ASP.Net retrieving Email

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api

I am using graph api and have also provided extended permission to retrieve email, but the email is a proxy email something like pps+118574594854286.806651951.f0a6e735e2c0a87531414040027be184@proxymail.facebook.com

now how can I get the real email or how the proxy email can be used to perform the same function of sending the email to the logged in facebook user.

Answer (score 0):

1).You need to request specific access to the users email adresses in your auth dialog link, for example:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=email,user_birthday
```

2). You (or more correctly, the app creator) need to be verified as a facebook developer. This is easily done via mobile phone.

3). When the user access your app and get the option to grant the permissions you request for your app, there's a small drop down menu where they can choose to let you access their real email adress or the proxy email adress. This is a bit of a pain according to me, but currently that's how it works.

Make sure the adress are correct and no special signs gets stripped away. "apps+xxxxx..." is the correct style of a proxy email adress.

You can send emails to proxy email adresses by using the Graph API function notifications.sendEmail:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/notifications.sendEmail/